# How to packetize H.263 into RTP packets after stream is encoded with FFMPEG

Tags: java, ffmpeg, rtp, h.263

I have a Java based VoIP Softphone (jPhoneLite) that supports H.263+ and H.264.
But currently the H.263 (RFC2190) is incomplete.
According to the RFC the data must be split up at MB (macroblock?) boundaries but I have no idea how to find them.
If you look at FFMPEG source /libavformat/rtpenc_h263_rfc2190.c in function ff_rtp_send_h263_rfc2190() you can see that the mb boundary info is passed to their packetizer from the encoder somehow.
I use ffmpeg to encode my video into H263 data but I don't know if ffmpeg provides a function to obtain these MB pointers/offsets.

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/rtpenc_h263_rfc2190.c

http://jphonelite.sourceforge.net

Any help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The H.26x bit stream is divided in layers,
generally each layer starts with unique sequence of bits.

1. Picture/frame layer: starting with PSC - picture start code. includes list of GOV - group of blocks .
2. GOV optionally starts with code. includes list of MB - macro blocks
3. MB - start with header and ends with code.

You can read about it in section: *3.2 GOB Numbering* of [rfc2190](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2190)

After reviewing ffmpeg code, the search for the start code is done by: ***ff_h263_find_resync_marker_reverse()*** in [rtpenc_h263.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/235381e674bf0921cbb7871946e2ff08bd84d6ba/libavformat/rtpenc_h263.c) .

Answer (score 0):

I prefer open source [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) written in Java.

Other option is [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html), open source as well with good mediastramer2 that supports h263/264 (msx264).  You can find relevant code there

Comment: I'm not looking for another softphone.  I'm the creator of jPhoneLite and just wanted help trying to implement H.263 RFC2190 in my project.  Thanks anyways.  Although maybe I can look into their code...